# How to get a variable within an Array

Tags: arrays, bash, variables

I have been banging my head on this problem and just can't figure it out

I have an Array which works fine except for the 1 value which is a variable and I cant figure out how to get the function to actually use the value of the variable

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

FILE_LIST=(
  "${file0}"
  /etc/file1
  /etc/file2/file2
  /etc/file3
)

CopyFiles() {
  local -a arr
  local eval_cmd i
  printf -v eval_cmd 'arr=( "${%q[@]}" )' "$2"
  eval "$eval_cmd"
  for i in "${arr[@]}"; do
    "$1"
  done
}

RevertFiles() {
  cp -pv "/tmp$i" "$i"
}

file0=/etc/file0 # it could also be /etc/fileA or any other file path

CopyFiles 'RevertFiles' 'FILE_LIST'
```

How do i get the for loop to use the value of $file0?

Comment: Forgive an additional question as a comment, but where is `$file0` assigned? What is is supposed to contain? The only reason I can see that it would not be included in `FILE_LIST` is that is was empty when the `FILE_LIST` array is filled?? If you want a literal `$file0`, then `single-quote` it to prevent the dereference or escape the `$` (e.g. `\$file0`). Is that what you are attempting?

Comment: Is `file0` set before initializing FILE_LIST array?  If so, its value will correctly show up in the loop.  Are you expecting the variable to get evaluated inside the loop?

Comment: lets say file0=/etc/file0 but could also be /etc/fileA or any other variation

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, No I am not looking for a literal $file0, file0 could be any file path

Comment: @codeforester yes file0 is set before I run the array.  If i echo $file0 right before the function i see the correct value but someone within the function it seems to be getting gobbled up

Comment: Then you need a `file0=/any/file/path` **before** you fill `FILE_LIST` with `FILE_LIST=(...)` or `file0` will be unset/empty. (I see your edit, if you fill it **above** `FILE_LIST`, your fine)

Comment: Run the script with set -xv and show the output here.

Comment: That is not set prior to the array, hence no value when array is created

Comment: so what you are saying is the array gets filled based on its location within the script? I guess that makes sense.  I was thinking it would get filled when i first call it.

Comment: Thanks @DavidC.Rankin i moved my array below, and its now working as expected!

Comment: Good, glad it helped. With variables, if it isn't set before you attempt to use it (in a top-down reading), it's empty `:)` Also, you can always check your shell scripts at [**ShellCheck.net**](http://www.shellcheck.net/).